# Add date to query

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime

I want to add time series to my database table autogenerated.
Suppose the column values should be

- 23-07-2021 00:05:00
- 23-07-2021 00:10:00
- 23-07-2021 00:15:00
- 23-07-2021 00:20:00
  and so on at an interval of 5 mins.

How do I do this in Oracle db?

Comment: Starting and ending when? How are you providing that information to the query?

Comment: @mathguy Starting 1st June 2021 and ending Current_date + 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can generate data like this recursively using hierarchical query

```
select to_date('23-07-2021 00:00:00', 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss') + level / 24 / 60 * 5 
  from dual 
connect by level <= 1000
```

Where

- to_date('23-07-2021 00:00:00', 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss') - is the start date
- level / 24 / 60 * 5  - 5 Minutes step.
- connect by level <= 1000 - a dummy limit has no other reason other than to stop recursion at some point

UPD. Additional reuirement from OP: "This just creates a temporary table. I wanted to insert these values to a new table. And the value should just be till current_date + 1"

```
create table ek_test as 
select to_date('23-07-2021 00:00:00', 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss') + level / 24 / 60 * 5 date_col
from dual 
connect by to_date('23-07-2021 00:00:00', 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss') + level / 24 / 60 * 5 < sysdate + 1
```

Comment: This just creates a temporary table. I wanted to insert these values to a new table. And the value should just be till current_date +1. @ekochergin